# How to reuse these Number background color 1-5 when 6 comes in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableView for this and for each cell it adds 1 number and change the color of background. Can you please tell me how to reuse these colors after 5 number. When cell 6 shows, it starts to show the color from 1.

```
//Gradient Color in cell
        let gradientLayer1 = CAGradientLayer()
        let colorTop =  UIColor.rgb(r: 247, g: 121, b: 133).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor.rgb(r: 251, g: 159, b: 168).cgColor
        gradientLayer1.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer1.frame = cell.viewNumber.bounds
        cell.viewNumber.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer1, at: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Where you have stored the number which cause color change?

Comment: Can you share from where are these values coming ? What is the data source ?

Comment: Are you aware of % operator? If so `colorIdx = cellIdx % 6` will do the trick (or something like this)

Comment: simply divide the (indexPath.row / 5) and get the index of the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your colors into an array:

```
let colors: [[CGColor]] =
    [[UIColor.rgb(r: 255, g: 171, b: 179).cgColor, UIColor.rgb(r: 255, g: 149, b: 169).cgColor],
     [UIColor.rgb(r: 0, g: 105, b: 155).cgColor, UIColor.rgb(r: 63, g: 142,b: 251).cgColor],
     [UIColor.rgb(r: 216, g: 24, b: 202).cgColor, UIColor.rgb(r: 239, g: 100, b: 225).cgColor],
     [UIColor.rgb(r: 0, g: 183, b: 131).cgColor, UIColor.rgb(r: 0, g: 219, b: 161).cgColor],
     [UIColor.rgb(r: 255, g: 140, b: 2).cgColor, UIColor.rgb(r: 243, g: 130, b: 63).cgColor]]
```

Note:  The table contains pairs of colors that are used to make the gradients.

In `cellForRowAt`, use `indexPath.row % colors.count` to select your colors.  Note: cells are reused, so you only want to add the gradient the first time.  When a cell is reused, you'll need to replace the colors in the gradient layer:

```
let gradColors = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]

// If there is already a gradient layer, replace the colors
// otherwise create the gradient layer and insert it
if let grad = cell.viewNumber.layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
    grad.colors = gradColors
} else {
    let gradientLayer1 = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer1.colors = gradColors
    gradientLayer1.frame = cell.viewNumber.bounds
    cell.viewNumber.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer1, at: 0)
}
```

Note:  I used this extension to `UIColor` to add the `.rgb` capability:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func rgb(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image: Image of gradients running in the simulator]

Comment: your code will show the first color in all the cells

Comment: My code works if you put it in the right place. The picture is from the simulator.

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?  Make sure you defined your colors array like I did.  Make it a property of your tableViewController.  The rest of the code goes in `cellForRowAt`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cell reusing , you should have a model array that contains  the color of every row gradient and set it in `cellForRow`